# Mulitple applicationsettings tag inside a web.config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, application-settings

Can I have more than one applicationsettings tag inside a Web.Config file?
What is the best way to store multiple connection strings inside a web config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one applicationsettings in your web.config, and you should store your connectionstrings in `<connectionstrings>`

Comment: Thank you for you prompt reply. If I use <connectionstrings> tag to store my connection strings,Will I be able to access it by creating an instance of the SqlConnection Object.
like SQlConnection  = new SqlConnection ()

Comment: This should work: SqlConnection = new  SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString);

Comment: Thank you soo much for all your help. Appreciated :)

Comment: No problemo, if my answer was was of any help to you, consider accepting it as a legit answer, by clicking the checkmark, it'll most likely help others in the future. :)